# Is it possible to mixin before the constructor is called?

Tags: ruby, mixins, ruby-2.0

I thought I'd make a mixin for logging to keep my code DRY. This is how it looks:

```
# Mixin that provides shortcuts for logging methods.
module Logging
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_exec {
      @logger_name = base.to_s
      @subloggers = []
      @logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
      @logger.level = Logger::FATAL
    }
  end

  def logger=(logger)
    @logger = logger
    @subloggers.each { |obj| obj.logger = logger }
  end

  def debug(&block)
    @logger.debug(@logger_name, &block)
  end

  def info(&block)
    @logger.info(@logger_name, &block)
  end

  def warn(&block)
    @logger.warn(@logger_name, &block)
  end

  def error(&block)
    @logger.error(@logger_name, &block)
  end

  def fatal(&block)
    @logger.fatal(@logger_name, &block)
  end
end
```

In theory, I should now be able to do this:

```
class SomeClass
  include Logging

  def foo_bar
    debug { "foo_bar is being executed" }
    fatal { "IT'S A TRAP" }
  end
end
```

The problem is that apparently `initialize` is called *before* the mixins are included, causing this to fail:

```
class SomeClass
  include Logging

  def initialize
    @cache = CacheClass.new
    @subloggers << @cache   # @subloggers is nil
  end
end
```

And I can't picture any way around it. I always create my dependencies in the constructor, and I need the Logging mixin to be available at that point. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong:

> The problem is that apparently initialize is called before the mixins are included, causing this to fail:

Contrary to what you wrote, `initialize` is not called. `@subloggers` is not initialized for the `SomeClass` instance. Are you thinking that `@subloggers` assigned in `Logging.included(base)` is the same variable as the `@subloggers` you are accessing from the `SomeClass` constructor? That should not be the case. An instance variable cannot be created before creation of the instance itself.

Comment: Any way to do what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: If those variables are supposed to be shared between instances, then you should define them either as class variables or instances variables on the class. If you want each instance to have different variables, you need to put that in the constructor.

Comment: So then there is no way for a mixin to define instance variables.

Comment: There is, but not before initialization of an instance. By the way, is this answer helping, or not?

Comment: I was under the misapprehension that `@var = "value"` in a class definition would mean that each class instance would have each their `@var` instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you mix in that class, those variables become instance variables on the class.  Not to be confused with class variables, or regular instance variables.  Check out this little irb conversation:

```
1.9.3p194 :012 > class Foo
1.9.3p194 :013?>   def self.bar
1.9.3p194 :014?>     @bar
1.9.3p194 :015?>     end
1.9.3p194 :016?>    def self.bar=(x)
1.9.3p194 :017?>     @bar=x
1.9.3p194 :018?>     end
1.9.3p194 :019?>    def self.show
1.9.3p194 :020?>     puts @bar
1.9.3p194 :021?>     end
1.9.3p194 :022?>   end
 => nil
1.9.3p194 :023 > Foo.bar=5
 => 5
1.9.3p194 :024 > Foo.bar
 => 5
1.9.3p194 :025 > Foo.show
5
 => nil
1.9.3p194 :026 > a=Foo.new
 => #<Foo:0x007fe9038e5dc0>
1.9.3p194 :029 > a.instance_variables
 => []
1.9.3p194 :030 > a.class.instance_variables
 => [:@bar]
```

Compare the results of your classes:

```
SomeClass.instance_variables
SomeClass.new.instance_variables
SomeClass.new.class.instance_variables
```